# "Transfer" object properties to object of different class

Tags: php

I have one object being the result of a database query, looking something like this (var_dump output):

```
object(stdClass)#17 (6) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(20) "Some Title"
  ["description"]=>
  string(41) "Some really good stuff. Description here."
  ["slug"]=>
  string(19) "some-slug-url"
  ["picture_url"]=>
  NULL
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "5.99"
}
```

I just need all property values "transferred" to a different class which has the same property names. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at PHP's [`get_object_vars()`-function](http://php.net/get_object_vars) to achieve the desired effect without tons of assignment statements:

```
foreach (get_object_vars($sourceObject) as $name => $value) {
    $destinationObject->$name = $value;
}
```

You should make sure that you add sufficient error-checking to this, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The simple and "failsafe" solution

```
$target = new MyClass;
$target->id = $source->id;
$target->title = $source->title;
// and so on
```

Its a little bit more to code, but the benefits are

- If some property of `$source` change, you will notice it (because its missing in `$target`)
- You can name the properties of `$target` completely independent from `$source`
- You see, what happens

Comment: Not bad either, but I've decided to go with the option described by elusive – I tried that approach and I agree that changes in the model would need cascading updates but since my project is rather tiny I'll probably get along very well with above solution. :)